# Unique scoring for redis leaderboard

Tags: redis

I am using redis to create a leaderboard and trying to figure out a nice way to deal with players who achieve the same high score (players with the same high score should be ordered by who achieved that high score first)

I had thought of doing the following...

```
zadd leaderboard highscore.timestamp player_id.attempt_number
```

However, when I do zrevrange the timestamps are obviously going to be in the incorrect order.

Example input:

```
zadd leaderboard 20.123 5.1
zadd leaderboard 20.125 5.2
zadd leaderboard 20.012 5.3
zadd leaderboard 21.024 5.4
```

Output:

```
zrevrange leaderboard 0 -1
5.4
5.2
5.1
5.3
```

Desired output:

```
5.4
5.3
5.1
5.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to do `zadd leaderboard highscore.(Long.MAX_VALUE - timestamp) player_id.attempt_number` (change Long.MAX_VALUE to whatever is a reasonable highest possible value for your timestamp - A signed 64 bit int will store about 300 million years worth of miliseconds, so that might not be needed)

EDIT: Don't forget to add leading zeroes :)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt and elegant response :)